# How do I plot series of points on rows in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib and Python 2.7

I have a MxN matrix of tuples, an x-coordinate and a speed. How do I plot M rows of points with N points in each row at the specified x-coordiantes? Preferrably with the first row at the top?

I've tried various examples from the documentation but honestly I haven't really found anything.

Here is a rough example of what I want to accomplish, the t-coordinate goes from 0 to M, the x range has a fixed size. The dots are placed in a horizintal line according to their values. Is it somewhat readable?
[image: Plot mockup]

Comment: Do you have an example image if what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that you want M different plot axes, stacked on top of each other? I'm confused by the statement "preferably with the first row at the top" part. Just doing a scatter plot of the (x,speed) values for all MxN pairs should be easy enough. Also, how large are we talking for M and N. If you do want stacked plots, and M is huge, it's not going to be readable.

Comment: Sorry, the "preferably with the first row at the top" just means that the t-axis is flipped. I tried adding a mockup. The speed should not be plotted, it is used during calculations. The data represents cars on a road at time t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random((10, 20))
x = x.cumsum(axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, row in enumerate(x):
    ax.plot(row, i * np.ones_like(row), 'ko')

ax.set_ylim([-0.5, 9.5])
ax.set_yticks(range(10))
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:**

@EMS is quite right, I missed a rather key point of your question.

However, if you have nested lists of tuples, just convert it to an array. It will be a 3D array that you can slice as you need for the x-position and velocity.  There's absolutely no need to generate a second dataset, and matplotlib will convert whatever you input to it into a numpy array regardless, so there's no performance penalty.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

data = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
        [(5, 6), (7, 8)]]

data = np.array(data)

x = data[:,:,0]
velocity = data[:,:,1]
```

This yields:

```
x: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 7]])

velocity:
array([[2, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Comment: This doesn't address the need to strip out the first element of tuples at each entry of a matrix, which seemed like a critical part of the question to me.

Comment: As this is only for a quick simulation I got away with generating two parallell sets of data (I know, it's horrible), and then thissolution worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: @EMS - I completely missed that part of the question.  If he has an "array of tuples", though, it's just a 3D array. Just convert it to an array (It sounds like nested lists) and slice it. No need to generate a new dataset.  It's just `x = data[:,:,0]` and `velocity = data[:,:,1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python script that makes fake data that should be somewhat like yours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num_rows = 7
num_cols = 10

# Make a fake data array that's just a list of lists.
# And each list has num_cols number of different tuples.
# The x-data is assumed to be the first coordinate of the
# tuple

my_data = []
for ii in range(num_rows):
    my_data.append([])
    for jj in range(num_cols):
        my_data[ii].append( (24*np.random.rand(),np.random.rand()) )


# Now plot the different rows as separate plots.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for ii in range(num_rows):

    # The y-axis values are just a constant based on the current row.
    cur_tvals = [ii]*num_cols

    # The x values are gotten by using a list comprehension to
    # grab just the first tuple element. 
    cur_xvals = [tup[0] for tup in my_data[ii]]

    # Add the current curve to the plot. Specifying '.' as the
    # symbol get rid of any lines connecting the markers.
    ax.plot(cur_xvals,cur_tvals,'.',markersize=5)

# Setting axes based on num_rows
ax.set_ylim([-0.5, num_rows-1+0.5])
ax.set_yticks(range(num_rows))
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

This plots the points as you want:
[image: plot as requested]